# interesting behaviour of order by with union all clause

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I encountered just an interesting behaviour of order by clause when query contains `union all`.

For example I have following query:

```
select * from dual order by 1
union all
select * from dual
```

It fails, what the?

Ok it seems that oracle just does not like `order by` followed by `union all`. Lets rewrite query to following:

```
select * from (select * from dual order by 1)
union all
select * from dual
```

It is fixed!

It will also work if I just swap two queries, so one with `order by` goes to the end:

```
select * from dual
union all
select * from dual order by 1
```

That seems to be inconsistent. So what is the cause of such behaviour? Is it some kind of bug or it is done on purpose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statement

```
select * from (select * from dual order by 1)
```

has no defined order at all. Only the outermost ORDER BY takes effect in SQL (except if there is a row limit set).

If you still happen to observe order in the query results this is a coincidence that can go away at any time.

In the statement

```
select * from dual
union all
select * from dual order by 1
```

The `order by` is attached to the `union all`, not the the 2nd `select`. It is therefore top-level and well-defined.

Use the last form. And put the `order by` into a new line to make this easier to read.

---

> How can I then sort just single select with union all?

The output order of union all is undefined without order-by clause. Certainly the two inputs are not guaranteed to be concatenated.

```
select *, 1 as Tag from dual
union all
select *, 2 as Tag from dual
order by Tag, 1 --simulate ordered concatenation of inputs
```